# How to merge 2 ByteBufs?

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to merge 2 ByteBufs into one single ByteBuf, how can i do that?

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteBuf a = Unpooled.buffer(4).writeByte(33).writeByte(44).writeByte(55).writeByte(66);
        ByteBuf b = Unpooled.buffer(4).writeByte(77).writeByte(88).writeByte(99).writeByte(22);

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
        a.readBytes(byteArray);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrayUtils.addAll(byteArray, b.array())));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
                Unpooled.copiedBuffer(a, b).array()
        ));
    }
}
```

The code above prints

> [33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 22]
>
> [77, 88, 99, 22]

I can easily merge byte arrays but i couldn't merge ByteBufs, i can't call ByteBuf.array() method and create a new ByteBuf with merged byte arrays on production (i get `UnsupportedOperationException: direct buffer` when i call `array()` so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your code has already read all of `a`'s four bytes:

```
a.readBytes(byteArray);
```

At this point `a`'s read index is past the end of data, so none of its bytes are copied.

Placing the code for copying the buffer ahead of reading fixes the problem:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
        Unpooled.copiedBuffer(a, b).array()
));
byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
a.readBytes(byteArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrayUtils.addAll(byteArray, b.array())));
```

Alternatively you can call `a.resetReaderIndex()` after `readBytes` to "rewind" the buffer back to the beginning.